# How to set modify ID of html element dynamically

Tags: javascript

I have textbox element as below:

```
<input type="text"  class="url" id="url" name="url" contenteditable="true"  style=" text-align: left; height: 30px; width:512px; " placeholder="Enter URL ..."/></input>
```

When user perform button click action, in called function I want to change the ID of textbox.

Is there anything like

document.setElementID?

I have already created input element so this will not help:

```
var hiddenInput = document.createElement("input");
    hiddenInput.setAttribute("id", "uniqueIdentifier");
```

Comment: What's wrong with `document.getElementById("url").setAttribute("id","myNewId")` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var hiddenInput = document.getElementById ('url');
hiddenInput.id = 'uniqueIdentifier';
```

or with jquery :

```
$('#url').attr('id','uniqueIdentifier');
```

Comment: I think hiddenInput.setAttribute("id", "uniqueIdentifier"); would still be valid for the first example.